# Why does my Oracle PreparedStatement sometimes never return despite no contention?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement, freeze

### Update 2/5/2014:

### Problem was resolved by rebooting the Linux server hosting the Oracle database.  The server had not been booted since May of last year even though Oracle itself had been restarted on a regular basis.

I have a couple of Java 1.6 programs that use an Oracle 11.2 database and the 11.2.0.3.0 ojdbc6.jar Oracle driver.  At seemingly random points it will apparently hang, never returning control from PreparedStatement.executeUpdate().

Frequently my program binds data to a BLOB column and in this case (again at random times) it may hang at a call to OutputStream.flush(), where my OutputStream is a wrapper for the OracleBlobOutputStream.

In both cases the thread is stuck waiting forever trying to read a socket for an Oracle response before it will continue.

Monitoring sessions in the Oracle database for my JDBC Thin Client with sqlDeveloper I can see that the session is waiting as shown with Seconds In Wait.   In the particular case of of flushing a blob, the ActiveSQL tab shows No Text Available.  In the case of hanging at PreparedStatement.executeUpdate() that tab will show the full text of my insert statement. In either case the Waits tab will show "SQL*Net more data from client", which to me indicates that the Oracle server is waiting for more data to complete the client request.

So I can see that the Oracle server seems to be waiting for the client to finish his request.  The client seems to have completed the request and is waiting for the server to return a response.

Could network errors be the cause of this?  I would think the client and server would be protected by the retry logic of a TCP/IP stream.  I frequently use this application over a VPN connection on the internet (against test instances of the database) where I'd expect more errors but I never see a problem in that context.

I've seen fixes for a getNextPacket() issue in the Oracle driver but as shown above we're using the latest driver and should have those.

The Contention tab never indicates anything, as I would expect.  From everything I can tell competing transactions are not the issue here.  And the program will still fail at night, when there's hardly any other activity than my program.

This code works flawlessly in my test environment.  It also works in a test environment at my client's site.  But in the production environment it fails.  It may insert 50-100K rows of data before failing.

In some cases it does not hang.  It throws inconsistent exceptions such as one about how you can only bind a LONG value to a LONG column.  This too I never see in testing on four different databases and the problem moves around from one table to another with no discernible pattern.

To the best of my knowledge dynamic SQL will work and the problem is specific to prepared statements.  But I can't be certain of that.

This production database is bigger than any of the test instances.  It is sized to handle about two terabytes of data and is probably 1/3 on the way to that goal.  All of the tablespaces have plenty of space and the rollback segment was recently enlarged by a factor of 3 and is very underutilized.

I'm not aware of a hang in auto-commit mode and it seems to hang only after a transaction accumulates a good bit of data.  But with the problem so random I can't conclusively say that.

This program worked for months without problem and then this started a couple weeks ago without any change to the software whatsoever.  The client's database has been steadily getting bigger, so that's a change. And I hear the client installed some network monitoring software about that time but I don't have any specifics on that.

Sometimes JDBC batching is in play, other times not and it still fails.

I'm pulling my hair out over this one, something I have so little of to work with!

Any insight from my friends at stackoverflow?

Here is a callstack where I waited to see Seconds in Wait at the server and then paused my client program in the eclipse debugger. Everything from OracleOutputStream on up is ojdbc6.jar code.

```
Thread [GraphicsTranslator:1] (Suspended)        
owns: T4CConnection  (id=26)    
owns: Input  (id=27)       
SocketInputStream.socketRead0(FileDescriptor, byte[], int, int, int) line: not available [native method]             
SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) line: 129             
DataPacket(Packet).receive() line: 293   
DataPacket.receive() line: 92      
NetInputStream.getNextPacket() line: 174          
NetInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) line: 119   
NetInputStream.read(byte[]) line: 94     
NetInputStream.read() line: 79 
T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket() line: 122        
T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read() line: 78  
T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1() line: 1040           
T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1() line: 1016            
T4C8TTIBlob(T4C8TTILob).receiveReply() line: 847            
T4C8TTIBlob(T4C8TTILob).write(byte[], long, byte[], long, long) line: 243               
T4CConnection.putBytes(BLOB, long, byte[], int, int) line: 2078  
BLOB.setBytes(long, byte[], int, int) line: 698      
OracleBlobOutputStream.flushBuffer() line: 215               
OracleBlobOutputStream.flush() line: 167            
ISOToDBWriter.bindElementBuffer(ParameterBinding, SpatialObject, boolean) line: 519               
ISOToDBWriter.writePrimitive(SpatialObject, boolean) line: 1720              
ISOToDBWriter.writeDgnElement(SpatialObject, Properties, String, boolean) line: 1427 
ISOToDBWriter.write(SpatialObject) line: 1405   
ISOHandler.inputObject(InputEvent) line: 864    
InputEventMulticaster.inputObject(InputEvent) line: 87               
Input(Input).notifyInput(Object, Object) line: 198            
Input(Input).notifyInput(Object) line: 157            
Input.readElement(int) line: 468               
Input.readElement() line: 403    
Input.run() line: 741        
GraphicsTranslator.processAllDgnFiles() line: 1190            
GraphicsTranslator.run() line: 1364          
Thread.run() line: 662
```

### Update 2/3/2014:

I've been able to do more testing at the client's site.  Apparently the problem is caused by network errors.  I wrote a small test program with straight-jdbc calls and it fails too.  It only fails against this specific database instance.  The test program binds increasingly long strings into a prepared statement it keeps executing and ultimately rolls back is transaction (if it gets that far).  The test program, rather than hang, sometimes throws an exception randomly as follows:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:208)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1046)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1336)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3613)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3694)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1354)
at com.byers.test.outage.TestPreparedInsert.insertThenRollback(TestPreparedInsert.java:81)
at com.byers.test.outage.TestPreparedInsert.runTest(TestPreparedInsert.java:54)
at com.byers.test.outage.TestPreparedInsert.main(TestPreparedInsert.java:28)
```

The test program inserts thousands of rows and runs at a pretty good clip till the insert strings get longer than about 1,300 bytes.  Then it gets increasingly slow and by the time the strings are around 1,500 bytes a single insert will take 30 seconds or more.  I suspect the problems start when the request exceeds a packet in size.

I ran WireShark and captured all IP packets going between me and the Oracle server.  Then I see lots of TCP ACKed unseen segment, TCP Previous Segment not captured, TCP Dup ACK 3#1, TCP Dup ACK 3#2, etc.  I'm no network expert but I'm smart enough to say "this is not good".

Unlike my production system, my test program does not actually cause Oracle to "hang" so far.  The Oracle session does not show Seconds In Wait and if I wait long enough the program continues (even though my patience with that has been limited).  I've also not seen the above exception thrown unless I run more than one instance of the program at the same time, although that too may be a matter of not waiting long enough?

Invocations of the below code such as:

```
insertThenRollback(con, 50, 2000, 0);
```

are pretty good at producing the errors.  Interestingly, starting out with big insert strings like 3000 bytes does not lead to errors until the program recycles at 4000 and counts back up into the 1300+ range.

```
private static void insertThenRollback(Connection con, int delayMs, int rowCount, int startCharCount)
        throws SQLException, InterruptedException
{
    System.out.println("Batch " + (++batchCount) + ". Insert " + rowCount + " rows with "
            + delayMs + "ms. delay between, then rollback");
    String sql = "Insert Into config (name,value) values(?,?)";
    PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    String insString = "";
    for (int c = 0; c < startCharCount; ++c)
    {
        int randomChar = (int) (Math.random() * DATA_PALLET.length());
        insString += DATA_PALLET.charAt(randomChar);
    }
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; ++i)
        {
            if (insString.length() > MAX_INSERT_LEN - 1)
                insString = "";
            int randomChar = (int) (Math.random() * DATA_PALLET.length());
            insString += DATA_PALLET.charAt(randomChar);
            String randomName = "randomName--" + UUID.randomUUID();
            System.out.println("Row " + (i + 1) + "->" + randomName + '/' + insString.length()
                    + " chars");
            stmt.setString(1, randomName);
            stmt.setString(2, insString);
            stmt.executeUpdate();
            Thread.sleep(delayMs);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        System.out.println("Rollback");
        con.rollback();
        stmt.close();
    }
}
```

This seems to put me on solid footing to tell the client that the problem is with their network.  Would you all agree?  Is it not also true that the client should be able to monitor their network somehow for these kinds of errors?  It seems almost silly to me that we would invest hundreds of hours of collective effort chasing a problem like this just to find out it is hardware or some kind of invasive software.  Are there ways to detect a high degree of these kinds of network errors by monitoring of some kind?

Comment: Are you closing `preparedStatement` and `Connection` objects?

Comment: Yes, all statements, connections, and blob objects get closed when the program is done with them.

Comment: BTW, are you using any kind of batch update as you are doing a 50-100k rows at a time? And post your code snippet, it does help for others to review.

Comment: One of my programs fails with no batching of any kind.  Others fail without batching.  Seems unrelated.

Comment: Posting a code snippet on this would be difficult because our code always uses abstractions or small wrappers around Oracle and JDBC APIs to encapsulate resource management and error recovery.  I'm working on a small test program to demonstrate the failure but I won't be able to try that out till tomorrow afternoon when I'm able to access the production database where it is failing.

Comment: whats the max heap allowed for the java VM ?

Comment: The network monitoring rings an alarm bell for me. I've seen border intrusion detection silently drop packets when it thought it saw something suspicious, even within a LAN, with indication either end. That would defeat failure retries, as the retry is just dropped as well, if not all further traffic on that connection. Are the software and DB on the same box? Are you seeing the issue when the same data is queried? I'd ask the network people if they've logged any issues at the times you've seen this, and/or ask for a rule exception for SQL*Net traffic to see if it stops.

Comment: Work-around option for time being can be the use of the connection property `oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout` (be careful with it: has to be larger than longest running query). That should ensure threads at least get un-stuck after a while.

Comment: Looks like a socket timeout/disconnect which could happen due to Oracle settings, or TCP/IP timeout, bad connectivity, etc. Take a look at keep alive settings, check how long idle connections stay connected before they get dropped.

Comment: @user3262576 My suggestion might be not well suited to your requirements or your logic. I had a similar program where I would want to insert huge chunk of data from Java to Oracle database. What I did to improve performance was I used Oracle Stored Procedures. From Java I pass parameters to stored procedures and SP does the batch processing. From Oracle 10g onwards it does allow to use bulk insert/update/delete. For me there was no issue of network traffic or packet size issue. The simple reason I have used stored procedure  was give the control to database engine to do the data manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Recently we had the same behavior in our production application, after restart the application the database persistence came back to work.

Looking for a clue of what could be happened I ended up in this article ([Understanding JDBC Internals & Timeout Configuration](http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/understanding-jdbc-internals-and-timeout-configuration/)) which explain in details how JDBC works and its different type of Timeout.

We will try to configure a timeout on JDBC (using **oracle.net.CONNECT_TIMEOUT** / 
**oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout**) to try avoid this issue in the future.